# NextJS with express server creates instance of server code every time it's called

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, next.js

I'm using next with an express server that when starts, also starts other services.
These services are an instance of a class each, and on the instance there are methods that return the necessary props, for example:

```
class Service_A extends ServiceSkeleton {
protected store_: any = { String };
constructor() {
    super("Service_A");
}
createBasePropsExample() {
    let session_id = uuid();
    let props = {
        session_id: session_id
    }
    return props
}
}

export const service_A = new Service_A();
```

As of my understanding, I should get these props like this in page.tsx:

```
async function getProps() {
  let properties = service_A.createBasePropsExample()
  console.log("properties: ", properties)
  return properties
}
export default async function Home() {
  const props = await getProps()

  return (
    <>

      {LandingPage(props)};
    </>
  )
}
```

However, every time a page loads, a new instance of Service_A gets created.
(I checked this by adding an `instance_id` to the `createBasePropsExample` function)

Is this how it should be? If it is, how could I create a service once than use that one instance?

Also, it might worth noting, that my folder structure is:

```
 -> src
    -> app
       - page.tsx
    -> server
       - service_a.ts
```